# MoveIt2 problem to install moveit_configs_utils package during binary downloading

Tags: ros2, moveit, installation, colcon, errors

I'm attempting to install MoveIt2 binary on the ROS2 Humble platform, but I'm having trouble installing the moveit_configs_utils package. Before that, I tried to install MoveitIt2 from the source build it could caused some troubles. I followed the official guide from the MoveIt2 Humble website. All the other packages were installed successfully.

I was attempting to use .pip when tried to fix it and received this problem while running colcon build --mixin release.

Error

```
--- stderr: moveit_configs_utils                                      
/home/tomas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
```

I also tried to install this package by downloading it from the internet and extracting it to the share directory via brute force. Is it possible to add the moveit_configs_utils package to an existing MoveIt2?

Thank you so much for your feedback!!

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I have installed MoveIt from source on ROS Humble and always used `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` to install the depenceies. Hope it helps!